# Where to download QA bands (cfmask bands) for surface reflectance Landsat7

Tags: data, landsat, usgs, landsat-7, landsat-5

I downloaded scenes from both Landsat 7 & 8 reflectance. However, QA bands are included in Landsat 8 but not 7. I selected "all data" when downloading. Anyone has a clue where the QA bands are for Landsat 7 (further more, Landsat 4-5?)

[QA for reflectance, USGS](http://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat_climate_data_records_quality_calibration.php)
This link says QA bands are available for all reflectance bands. Just couldn't find them.

Comment: Downloaded from where? I don't see an "all data" option on EarthExplorer or ESPA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just downloaded a Landsat 7 Surface Reflectance scene from [USGS EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). It contains QA bands.

[image]

If you are ordering from the [USGS ESPA](https://espa.cr.usgs.gov/ordering/new/), CFMask should be included by default in the Surface Reflectance product, but can be ordered separately (tick the CFMask box).

[image]

Comment: http://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat_climate_data_records_quality_calibration.php But here it indicates there are QA bands for landsat 4-5, 7

Answer (score 3):

If you download Collection-1 Landsat Images, both Landsat 7 and Landsat 8 Higher Level Data Products will come with pixel QA band. Otherwise you need to download the CFMask which has the same information but calculated with a different algorithm.

For more information you can check https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-surface-reflectance-quality-assessment website.

Please be informed that its announced on the ESPA site that starting from June 2nd CFMask wont be processed for Landsat Collection 1 Higher-Level data products.